# How do I push my balance/transaction data from Treasury into my accounting software (Xero)

Tags: transactions, xero-api, accounting, xero

We've build a treasury product which enables Founders to invest in MMFs. Founders park their cash on our platform and accrue interest. We need to find a way to push their balance, deposit, withdrawal and interest data to Xero (their preferred accounting tool) automatically.

Does this require becoming a Xero Financial Services Partner? How might we do this?

We're just exploring different solutions currently - it looks like creating a Bank Feed might require you to be a services partner first? Otherwise pushing these actions as 'transactions' to Xero might be one approach we could explore.